# CSS changes when window is made small

Tags: css, mobile

I've run into an issue with my wordpress site. When the window size is made small, especially in a mobile browsing scenario, the font size is increased to 16px and the #wrap width is changed to 460px down from 960px.

We want to keep the entire site at a 960px minimum as a quick solution to a mobile browsing problem whilst we take the time to implement something more long term.

The thing is, this change is reflected in CSS verified with FireBug

Here's the website in question: http://turbulentlabs.com

I've tried overriding it in CSS but it just doesn't take. Kind of at a dead end here, not even sure what to ask without being too general. Any thoughts?

Comment: So it seems that something is causing #header #navbar #container and  #footerbg to be changed from 960px width to 460px width when the browser width goes below a certain amount. I'm trying to figure out how to stop that change so these elements stay at 960px.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is in `style.css`, around line 2100.  Here's the related lines:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 524px)
#wrap {
width: 460px;
padding: 0px 16px;
}
```

See that `max-width`?  That means it will fire when the screen (window) is less than 524px.  Remove that and you will remove your responsive theme action.

Edit to add: if you look at firebug, it will tell you what lines and what css file are being called for each style.  Those lines will change when the style being called changes.  You may need to pull firebug out into its own window to see it easier.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Firebug or Chrome developer tools to look at the css in the "shrunken" window.  The theme probably has media queries built into it's css.

Kinda ironic that responsive css is a "problem", seeing that it is the wave of the future....  The person who wrote the theme would probably say "It's not a bug, it's a feature"!

To keep things static, you could remove or comment out the media queries - but look at the css carefully, since the cool kids say to build the page with mobile-first layout and then elaborate it as the screen size gets wider.

the quick/dirty solution is to remove the media queries themselves (assuming that they start at narrow and scale up to 960...).  Keep the css *contents* of the media queries, just remove the media query statements and their {}.  Chances are you will be making multiple changes to the same selectors, but hey, that is what quick / dirty involves....   Oh, and be sure you back up the unmodified css in case it all goes to hell!!!

Comment: Responsive css that is aware of the screen size is indeed a feature.  The OP just doesn't like that feature, and wants to remove it rather than optimize for mobile browsers.  That's fine, but don't mock the CSS for being written properly.

Comment: sorry, I wasn't mocking the css at all, just the irony of good practices being the issue....  I usually end up having to add media queries in to CSS, and the OP wants to remove them.  I haven't seen the whole css but from the looks of that perhaps the theme was written for a wide screen and the media queries added in for small screens later.  If that is the case, it could just be commented out / removed.  I absolutely agree that OP should re-do the css so it works well on mobile.